# Page directives inherits property

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm just wondering whether anyone knows what Inherits attribute means inside this Page directive and why it uses ._Default.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to MSDN:-

> Defines a code-behind class for the page to inherit. This can be any
>   class derived from the Page class. This attribute is used with the
>   CodeFile attribute, which contains the path to the source file for the
>   code-behind class.

So lets say you have a page `Default.aspx` with following Page directive:-

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="MyNamespace.Default" %>
```

`CodeBehind` attribute tells you the name of the compiled file that contains the class associated with the page.

Let's say Default.aspx.cs looks like this:-

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   public partial class Default: System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       //
   }

   public class Employee
   {
      //
   }
}
```

Since in the `Default.aspx.cs` file there can be multiple classes (Default & Employee) in this case, `Inherits` attribute specifies which class to inherit.